# Why can't I get individual bar colors in a candlestick chart in highstocks.js for more than 55 bars?

Tags: javascript, colors, highcharts

I found this weird behavior when I tried to apply individual colors to a column chart in a candlestick chart in `highstocks.js`.

I made a [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtgsr9ww/) example, but all I changed from the [original candlestick example](http://jsfiddle.net/gh/get/jquery/1.9.1/highslide-software/highcharts.com/tree/master/samples/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume/) was the values for the column (volume) chart from:

```
volume.push([
    data[i][0], // the date
    data[i][5] // the volume
]);
```

to:

```
volume.push({
    'x': data[i][0],
    'y': data[i][5],
    'color': 'green'
});
```

So when I change the number of bars I push into `ohlc` and `volume` from 54 to 55 (instead of `dataLength`) the colors are suddenly not applied anymore.

Try for your self, with a 'small' number of bars (<55 for me) the green color is applied just fine, but for a larger number of bars (>=55 for me) the volume bars are black and not green.

How can I avoid this? I want the colors to apply regardless how many bars I am plotting of course.

(This is just a simple toy example, in my real application the number of bars are far greater and colored depending on rules.)

Comment: weird, the color is apllied in my [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jtgsr9ww/2/)

Answer (score 1):

I found [an answer on the Highcharts forum](http://forum.highcharts.com/post102763.html#p102763). I need to disable the `dataGrouping` to make it work. Adding the column series as :

```
{
    type: 'column',
    name: 'Volume',
    data: volume,
    yAxis: 1,
    dataGrouping: {
        units: groupingUnits,
        enabled: false
    }
}
```

will make it all work. I see the volume bars don't plot at all for large timeseries though...